# Usability problem with "sticky" Microsoft Azure banner ads

Tags: bug, mobile-web, user-experience, site-ads

I contribute fairly often to Stack Overflow, and sometimes I do so using mobile Chrome browser from my Android phone.  With most banner ads, I can drag the screen using the ads as a starting point, and they do not open.  However, with a certain predatory type of Microsoft Azure ad, even *touching* the ad *without* releasing causes the popup to open.  There is no way around this from what I have seen.  This is a usability problem for me, because it means I either have to go out of my way to not use that part of the screen, or I have to close the Google ad-words ad, which requires at least 2 clicks (and often many more, as attempting to close will inadvertently open the ad).

I expect that many will suggest to me to either switch/upgrade phones, use the mobile app, or just contribute from desktop.  My phone and mobile Chrome browser are completely up to date, and I find that using the full site on mobile (with responsiveness disabled) is still the best user experience, only second to using the desktop site.

Is this a problem with Stack Overflow itself, or has Microsoft found a way to slip in "sticky" ads that open by themselves?

Comment: I use the mobile view on my iPhone quite often, but have not yet run into this. The behavior you describe sounds absolutely awful, and even if its proximate cause is predatory behavior on Microsoft's part, it should be more than enough for the Stack Overflow ads team to cancel these ads. I personally use the responsive version of the desktop site on my phone because it gives me access to the full suite of moderator tools. I wonder if that's why you've run into these ads when I haven't? Or maybe I've just been lucky...

Comment: @CodyGray Well I am using a recent Samsung Galaxy Android phone with Chrome browser.  I don't know who is at "fault" here, whether Google AdWords or maybe SE for allowing such CSS/HTML to even run in their site.  I am used to it by now, but was wondering if anyone else has this issue.

Comment: It's unlikely Microsoft at fault, but the slimy ad company they use.